# Silverlight 4 - ListBox auto scroll to last added item - mvvm light binding - no code behind

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I found 2 solution for this problem in WPF , however in Silverlight 4 it doesn't work ,   code can't

compile ,

WPF exmaple : http://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/listbox-automatically-scroll-currentitem-into-

view/

Any Silverlight 4 extender that does work?

Comment: Have you tried to apply same in SL4? Seems like it is suitable for it.

Comment: UIPropertyMetadata does not exist in SL